# Check if Magento 2 is using pub directory

Tags: magento2, static-content, directory

How can we check if the website is using pub directory or not, independent of its mode?

Is there any Magento function present to check the root document?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And finally after many testing, I found the most relevant solution to handle this. Code is as below:

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

protected $_directoryList;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    DirectoryList $directoryList,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_directoryList = $directoryList;

    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}
```

And now the pub directory can be checked by the condition

```
$pub = $this->_directoryList->getUrlPath("pub");
if ($pub == "pub") {
    //pub is not being used
} else {
    //pub directory is being pointed
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**pub:**
The pub directory is where the publicly exposed files are located. This is the directory that
we should set as root when setting up Apache or Nginx. The pub/index.php file is what
gets triggered when the storefront is opened in a browser.

**Try following code to get Directory Path and Current Mode:**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

try{

    require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

    $params = $_SERVER;
    $bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
    $objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

    $directoryList = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList');
    $root = $directoryList->getRoot();

    $state = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
    $mode = $state->getMode();

    echo "Project Directory Path: " . $root . "<br/>";
    echo "Current Mode: " . $mode;

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Never use direct `objectManager`

Comment: @KeyurShah -  I've posted an external/root script and you can use direct objectManager in it, don't worry about it. Because personally I'm not recommending to use direct objectManager in the module as per M2 standards.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know If I understand your question correctly but let me try, If you want to find your project root directory then you can find it like,

```
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

protected $directoryList;


public function __construct(
    ...
    DirectoryList $directoryList    
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->directoryList = $directoryList;  
    ....
}

    $rootDir = $this->directoryList->getRoot()
```

And yes, you are right `Magento2` use `pub` directory `index.php` If your current mode is `production` otherwise It uses root `index.php`. If you want to check current mode by code then you can check it like this,

```
use Magento\Framework\App\State;

protected $state;


public function __construct(
    ...
    State $state
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->state = $state;
    ....
}

    $currentMode = $this->state->getMode();
```

`$currentMode` can be `developer` or `production` or `default`.

Comment: Thanks Keyur for detailed info but please note, as per my understanding, there is no connection between the Magento modes and using pub directory, you can use any mode even the Magento is pointed to pub directory.
Also, I will try with directoryList class and update you. Thanks

Comment: sorry but I tried with many version of Magento (EE and CE)but it does automatically start pointing to pub directory when the mode is changed. Can you please also test once?

Comment: sorry but this getRoot() did not work for me.

Comment: yes i am using Magento as i mentioned in earlier comment :)